# Why can't I overclock a rooted Samsung Galaxy GT-I7500 beyond the default maximum 528MHz?

Tags: setcpu, samsung-galaxy-i7500

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy GT-I7500 running stock Donut (Android 1.6). I tried a couple of overclocking apps such as SetCPU and CPU Master, but none of them let me actually "over"-clock the CPU, because I can't set the maximum to be more than the default 528 MHz. I have read about speeds of 624 and/or 710 MHz possible with either the Galaxo custom ROM or GAOSP, but I want to achieve those kinds of speeds with stock Donut.

I've tried GAOSP b3 (Gingerbread) and Galaxo 1.6.3.4, but I prefer the feel of stock 1.6 (that's why I love my stock Nexus S running 2.3).

Is it possible to set the CPU speed beyond 528 MHz in my rooted Samsung Galaxy GT-I7500? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my understanding that some ROMs allow for Overclocking, whereas others dont. It depends on how the kernel is setup. I couldnt Overclock my Samsung galaxy s2 for example on the stock rom with it rooted. I could however once I installed Cyanogen. Perhaps that is the case.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is true. Galaxo is a modded version of the stock 1.6 with a kernel that allows for overclocking, whereas the original, stock 1.6 kernel doesn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Donut you're using an older kernel, or perhaps the presets for your phone from autodetect don't include the desrired frequencies.  From [SetCPU's manual](http://www.setcpu.com/):

> In rare situations and in older kernels, and when SetCPU cannot get
>   root access, SetCPU may not be able to autodetect the full range of
>   speeds supported by the kernel. If this is the case, you can configure
>   SetCPU to use custom frequencies. To get started, you'll need the list
>   of frequencies your kernel can support in kHz (not MHz!).
>
> Create a plain text file called “setcpu.txt” and place it on the root
>   directory of your SD card or on your SD card's ext partition (/sdcard/
>   or /system/sd/). The text files should sort the frequencies on one
>   line by comma, from lowest to highest. For example, the following is a
>   valid config file:
>
> 125000,250000,500000,550000,600000
>
> To store the custom frequency list on your phone, save it as “setcpu”
>   with no extension and put it in /data/. SetCPU reads from the SD card
>   first and uses that text file if present, then tries to read from
>   /data/.
>
> To configure SetCPU to read your custom frequencies, go back to the
>   device selection screen (in the Main tab, press Menu > Device
>   Selection), choose “show other frequencies” if necessary, and choose
>   the custom config option at the very bottom.

If you don't want to do that, you can also manually choose a different model of phone  that offers the frequencies you're looking to use instead of using auto detect.

Comment: Is that just a very elaborate way of saying RTFM? :-) Thanks for the tip - I'll certainly try this tonight!

Answer (score -1):

The look and feel of CM7 is superior compared to most stock rom's. So if your reason for not switching from the stock rom is the look n feel, you wont be disappointed with CM7.

Get CM7 for your phone from cm.get, install it. Once done go to

> Setting --> CyanogenMOD settings --> Performance --> CPU Settings --> Change Min Frequency

That is it, but be careful you can screw up your system, there are available governors, i suggest you use them.

Comment: The OP explicitly said they want to keep their current ROM, so telling them to use CM isn't helpful.

Comment: My reason for not switching from the stock ROM is that anything else isn't stock. I love original Android and I hate customisations such as TouchWiz and Sense or even third-party launchers. Besides, Cyanogenmod isn't available for the i7500 directly. That's what GAOSP is for - it's a port of CM for the i7500. I've already tried GAOSP (based on CM7/Gingerbread), and I wasn't happy with the feel.

Comment: @Logos I only suggested CM7 in case look and feel was the reason..
aalaap my bad did not have knowledge of that.